# iOS 12 - oneTimeCode OTP delegate

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios12, one-time-password

Is there any `delegate` getting fired when the user taps the **OTP** suggestion that **iOS** provides?

I know that I could use `UITextFieldDelegate` methods to detect changes in the `textfield`'s `text` property, but knowing that the user has pressed the button would make things so much easier...

Comment: after quite a research i was also unable to find any delegate directly for this purpose. But i find otp normally implement on empty text field. so`textFieldDidBeginEditing` with zero text help full in this regard

Answer (score 3):

According to Apple's article: [About the Password AutoFill Workflow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow)

> For iOS apps, the system always sends a textDidChangeNotification notification when a view has been modified. It also calls one of the delegate methods of the view—but the exact method depends on the view’s type:
>
> UITextField: The system calls your UITextFieldDelegate object’s textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:) method.
>
> UITextView: The system calls your UITextViewDelegate object’s textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:) method.
>
> Custom View adopting the UITextInput protocol: The system calls the insertText(*:) method or replace(*:withText:) in the UIKeyInput protocol.

You can create a subclass of `UITextField` or `UITextView` and override insertText(*:) method and replace(*:withText:) method, it will be called when user tap quickbar.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I found that when I got a text in  `Should change Charater` I got two empty spaces, there I come to know that it is autofill characters, so according to it, I update my four text field one by one.

Comment: I'm facing same issue. Receiving two empty spaces, how did you resolve this?